# @Security annotation and user parameter

Tags: symfony

In a controller, I have an action meant to display a user. The argument is the user to be displayed and is automatically fetched through a parameter converter.
Now I want to secure this action (displaying a user profile) so that only users with the USER_VIEW permission (currently implemented as a custom Voter) have access.
Using an @Security annotation it would look like:

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('USER_VIEW', user)")
 */
public function showAction(User $user) {...}
```

This doesn't work because the user variable in the expression refers to the authenticated user rather than the action argument.
[The documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) mentions that, but this is rather unfortunate.

How can I fix this issue and get my $user argument passed to the security expression? I could rename it, but perhaps there's something better to do.

I was also wondering if this should be considered a bug in Symfony, since 'user' is a rather common word, perhaps it should be renamed to something more specific such as 'authenticated_user' or 'security_user' or something. The same goes for the other 3 variables that are passed to the expression by Symfony: 'token', 'request', 'roles'.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible via annotation + expression language. You must create a custom Voter or ACL

Comment: Can you explain the use case? I can't imagine how you need restrict access to user who don't browse your site actually.

Comment: Rename your action parameter to somethig else. e.g: `$userToShow`, then in the annotation you can use `@Security("is_granted('USER_VIEW', userToShow)")`

Comment: @felipsmartins 'USER_VIEW' is actually a custom voter's attribute.

Comment: @Fracsi, yes, that's what I've done. I was wondering if there was something better to do. I thought about using the 'request' expression variable, but I don't think it would hold the User object, only its id.

Comment: Good questions. I have the same problem in an API with Requests/URL's like `PUT /users/{id}/profile`. Did you find another way than renaming the parameter?

Comment: @HKandulla no, I haven't.